# What was the most intense beam ever sent from Earth?

Tags: radio-communication, record, radar, radio-telescope

By a freak coincidence sensors on a passing alien ship a hundred light years away had picked up a faint artificial blip from Earth, thereby discovering our inhabited planet. But *which blip was it?*

**Question:** What was the most intense beam ever sent from Earth?

To avoid any ambiguities or confusion introduced by comments, well use [radiant intensity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiant_intensity) with units like W/sr,

Since we're talking far-field where everything drops as $1/r^2$ I'll define intensity as power per unit solid angle (e.g. kW/sr), though if it turns out to be more helpful, *spectral intensity or W/sr/Hz.

So we're looking for a lot of power and a large diameter to wavelength ratio.

Answers don't have to, but can consider issues like instantaneous vs average power and even the dispersion of pulsed signals (slightly different speeds) due to interstellar plasma, the same way they measure the distance to pulsars and FRB's ([Just how fast is a Fast Radio Burst thought to be?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/29487/7982))

- [What radio signals have NASA transmitted to outside our solar system?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/44890/12102)
- [Has DSS-43 ever been used in high power mode (>>20 kW) for an emergency situation?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18956/12102)
- [Why was the 100m Green Bank dish needed together with DSN's 70m Goldstone dish to detect Chandrayaan-1 in lunar orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20582/12102) (radar off the limb of the moon)
- [How soon after "The Eagle" landed did they first attempt to bounce a laser off the Moon? When did it first succeed?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33962/12102) (I'm sure they missed the Moon at least a few times over the decades)
- [How can just making the ground broadcast stronger neutralize a zombie(sat)?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19386/12102) (my favorite)
- [over the horizon radar](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/48057/12102)
- [However, Goldstone’s radar is not as powerful as Arecibo’s, so it does not have the same range into space, meaning that fewer NEOs could be characterized by radar.](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/48633/12102)<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup> [RIP Arecibo](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/40875/7982)

- [Are we less safe now that Arecibo is no more?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/38585/7982)
- [What will succeed the Arecibo Observatory?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/39948/7982)

Comment: Far-field for a collimated beam isn't 1/r^2, though.  MIght want to calculate peak power at center of the Airy disk instead.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft **Disagree x 2.** In the far field the intensity pattern for these maintains a constant shape when plotted against *angle*, and it's height varies as $1/r^2$ where $r$ is the distance from source to observer. It's not going to be Airy because the sources (either spatially filtered lasers or microwave feed horns) do not illuminate the aperture uniformly. Airy disk is the Fourier transform of a 2D circular "top hat" but that's not what happens in these transmission systems; the primary apertures are somewhat under-filled *by design* in order to reduce power spillage over the edges.

Comment: Note that I've suggested units of kW/sr specifically for this reason.

Comment: OK, fair enough -  I was looking at the optical regime where it's 'easier' to generate a uniform intensity source.  Agreed about radio-wavelength transmitters.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft with lasers there is often plenty of power so we just way over-expand the beam and use the center flat-ish part. Top-hat beam formers do exist but they are difficult and finicky devices to use. But the laser that's bounced off the moon has no extra power to spare, so they have probably use a gaussian beam illuminating the aperture and no other special beam shaper. I'm almost certain of this but it's worth looking it up now.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft so I've just asked [When they shoot lasers at the Moon for ranging, what is the shape of the beam?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50389/12102)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft and added an answer

Comment: The most intense (but brief) signal from Earth was definitely the detonation of the Tsar Bomba 50megaton bomb. The signal of an atmospheric detonation of a thermonuclear weapon is quite distinctive, and many, *many* magnitudes stronger than any directed radio signal.