# How to calculate laser link spot size

Tags: mathematics, optical, optical-communication

In the [reseach paper](https://elib.dlr.de/146233/1/Schwarz-2021-A_Laser_Link_from_Lunar_Surface_employing_Line-of-Dight_MIMO-FRONTIERS_Space_Technology.pdf) " A laser link from lunar surface..." ,  chapter 2.1.3.:

> When employing, for example, 20 cm diameter apertures at the
> transmitter telescopes and considering a carrier wavelength of λ =
> 1,064 nm, a full width at halfmaximum (FWHM)-divergence angle of
> approximately θdiv = 3.25 µrad is achieved. This divergence of θdiv =
> 3.25 µrad will produce spot sizes of about 1.2 km diameter on Earth-ground.

I am trying to follow the calculation and can't get the result.

With the given wavelength and diameter I can compute :
$$ \frac{\lambda}{d} = \frac{1064\,\text{nm}}{ 20\,\text{cm}} = 53.2\cdot 10^{-7} $$
The distance I can compute using sin-law:
$$  L = \frac{ D}{\sin (\theta)} =  \frac{20\,\text{cm}}{\sin (3.25\,\text{mrad})}  $$

Footprint =$ \frac{\lambda}{d} L$

At the end, I didnt get the same result.

How was it computed?

Comment: The link distance L does not need to be calculated as it is given in table 2 with 354.000km. The footprint, in general, is λL/d but usually gets multiplied by a factor based on the beam shape. In this case, they would have used a factor of ≈ 0,64. 
[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/55171/29979)  from a similar question might help you how to calculate the factor.

Comment: the text you cite says µrad, you use mrad. That's a factor of 1000 off.